# React - Passing a ref into a component which uses ForwardRef

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-typescript

I am building a custom Dropdown component which uses React-Select under the hood. I'd like to add support for refs. I have declared a ref in the app using `useRef` and am passing this into the component like this:

```js
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import { useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const dropdownRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown id="hello" ref={dropdownRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In the Dropdown component I'm using ForwardRef like this:

```js
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export interface DropdownProps {
  id: string;
}

const Dropdown = forwardRef(({ id }: DropdownProps, ref) => (
  <Select id={id} ref={ref} />
));

export default Dropdown;
```

However I am getting a Typescript error:

**Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Select<unknown, false, GroupBase>> | undefined'.**

I have tried swapping out the React Select for another component and I get a similar issue so I think this is a general React/Typescript issue rather than anything specific to React Select.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-tdd-dd4o79?file=/src/Dropdown.tsx:0-245)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly surprised, because normally when you specify the hook's initial value as `null` the type inference is clever enough.

I don't know `react-select` very well but have you tried passing a string as an initial value, and deleting the `<HTMLSelectElement>` from your app component? Let the package's TS definitions do the work...

Comment: I did just try what you suggested on the Code Sandbox I've linked to in the question with no joy. I've updated it now to use a standard HTML select but I'm still getting the same error so think this is a general React Typescript problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-tdd-dd4o79?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You should defind forwardRef type, it's a generic function:

```
const Dropdown = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement,DropdownProps>(( { id }: DropdownProps, ref) => (
  <select id={id} ref={ref}>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
));
```

Comment: My select is a custom React component called React Select. I think you're right that I need to add types to the forwardRef but I think it needs to be something other than HTMLSelectElement hence the error in bold above.

Comment: ref = { ref } can only be used for HTML element, not a React component.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the props to your `forwardRef` so it knows what types you are trying to forward, as such:

```js
import { forwardRef } from "react";

export interface DropdownProps {
  id: string;
}

const Dropdown = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, DropdownProps>(({ id }, ref) => (
  <div>
    <select id={id} ref={ref}>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
));

export default Dropdown;
```

The first template argument will be helpful to determine the type of ref you are trying to forward, the second will define the arguments your component will receive.
A good cheatsheet [here](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forward_and_create_ref/) for reference.